# Compile Dlib for webassembly

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, emscripten, dlib, webassembly

I am trying to build dlib for webassembly using emscripten but I am not sure how to do so.

Currently, dlib generates executables and not bytecode which is needed for emscripten. Is there some way to get around this issue?

Currently this is what i am doing (from within the dlib-19.4 folder.

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
emmake make
```

for the next step, I need to input a bytecode file however, dlib seems to just generate executables which the `emcc` command will not accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can read from Dlib's documentation is that it has a lot of features that emscripten does not provide including threading and so on. So you will need to exclude functionality thats not supported.

Also referring to [How to Compile](http://dlib.net/compile.html) section, it mentions how to use Dlib without Cmake.
It has a simple gcc example for SVM.

You should probably use this approach ie include the appropriate dlib headers in your project, write your functions and expose them for emscipten.

Then after building the js file you should be able to call the "exposed" functions from JS.